# Write ascii characters to putty from keyboard with Sikuli

Tags: putty, sikuli

I'm trying to send some commands to terminal by putty using sikuliX. The problem is that some commands need to use characters like "@", ">" but when I'm trying to write it via keyboard (For example, <kbd>alt</kbd> + 64 for "@"), doesn't work. Any idea? Here is my code example:

```
openApp("notepad.exe")
sleep(2)
type("64",KeyModifier.ALT)
```

**PS:** I can't use `paste()`, because putty receive content from that command.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, the Java AWT Robot that is used internally by Sikuli's `type()`, is restricted to the use of Java defined key constants that are mapped to the standard layout of the US-EN qwerty keyboard. Hence the usage of `type()` is generally restricted to whatever you can produce with your keyboard.

Saying that I would still expect the <kbd>Alt</kbd> combination to work.

Try asking this question on [Sikuli launchpad](https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli) and when you get an answer, update it here. It's a good question.

Comment: Thanks Eugene S. I knew about the fact of Sikuli only works with US-EN querty keyboard and that's because I'm trying with ALT + 64. I tried with keyDown(KeyModifier.ALT) and keyUp() too and still not working. I'll ask to Sikuli launchpad and post the solution here :-]

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works but I think that should exist more. I used the clipboard to paste the entire command that I want to send. Here is the explanation:

#### Using the clipboard

```
App.setClipboard("ssh user@hostname > /path/to/save/file.txt") # Here we save the command into clipboard to paste inside putty
if exists("puttyScreen.txt",10):
    rightClick("puttyScreen.txt") # Here we paste the content of the clipboard
```